# How to make ignore a userid using the command discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

This is the code:

```
@bot.command(name="add")
async def _blacklist_add(self, user: discord.Member):
        """Adds user to bot's blacklist"""
        if user.id not in self.blacklist_list:
            self.blacklist_list.append(user.id)
            fileIO("blacklist.json", "save", self.blacklist_list)
            await self.bot.say("User has been added to blacklist.")
        else:
            await self.bot.say("User is already blacklisted.")

@bot.command(name="remove")
async def _blacklist_remove(self, user: discord.Member):
        """Removes user to bot's blacklist"""
        if user.id in self.blacklist_list:
            self.blacklist_list.remove(user.id)
            fileIO("blacklist.json", "save", self.blacklist_list)
            await self.bot.say("User has been removed from blacklist.")
        else:
            await self.bot.say("User is not in blacklist.")
```

I want to know how to import JSON so that I can stop use abusing my bot, if you can help me.

Comment: Manage JSON with the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module.  Maybe check the users permissions before allowing them to blacklist someone?  That would require passing the context into the command and then looking at `ctx.message.author`

Comment: sorry i'm busy yesterday cannot see your messages.

Comment: ik
ctx.message.author
but i want all the discord used id in json file
then make ignore user to use command

Comment: the example for bot admin


`ids = [
"249928002161344512",
"387539916525142016",
"359951141343068182",
"308293489827774465"
]
`
    
`@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def setgame(ctx,* ,arg1):
       if ctx.message.author.id in ids:
        await bot.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='{}'.format(arg1)))      
       else:
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Bot Creator Permission", description="You don't have permission to use this command.", color=0xe60000)
        await bot.say(embed=embed)
`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the json module.

Assuming you have a file in the same directory as your bot (named "ids.json"), which you want to load the IDs from:

```
import json

with open("ids.json", "r") as f:
    ids = json.load(f)
```

All you need to put in the "ids.json" file is

```
["249928002161344512", "387539916525142016", "359951141343068182", "308293489827774465"]
```

You are now free to use the `ids` variable in the same way as you are now.

If you want to save the content of the `ids` variable to the file, you can use `json.dump(ids, f)`

```
with open("ids.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(ids, f)
```

However, you do need to be careful of using the file too much. Dumping a lot can cause issues where data is not saved to the file properly.